# Using TBBC Money/Currency Bundle for Symfony/Bootstrap Forms

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, currency

I don't think this question has been raised looking at the history and on google... 
I'm discovering symfony2 for a personal project and I'm not sure to take the problem the right way when it comes to implementing a form with TBBC Money/Currency bundle (found on packagist).

I have a "Expense" class containing a price field (type "Money") and for which I want to create a form.

In my "ExpenseType" file I have the following:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('title', TextType::class)
                ->add('actualDate', DateType::class, array('widget' => 'single_text'))
                ->add('comment', TextareaType::class)
                ->add('price', MoneyType::class, array())
                ->add('user', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'VPAccountsBundle:User',
                    'property' => 'username'))
        ;
    }
```

On my twig file displaying the form I have:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 control-label">
                {{ form_label(form.price, "Amount" ) }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                {{ form_widget(form.price , { 'attr':{ 'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Amount' } } ) }}
            </div>
            {{ form_errors(form.price) }}

        </div>
```

What I get is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6Ede.png).

What I would like to get is a bootstrap input with dropdown button (see [mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/se5m0.png)). but I really don't know how to proceed.

Has anyone faced this kind of situation? Any help would be appreciated! :)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have a while working with Symfony2 and Forms is a great tool which makes me ask: why you need a external bundle for create a Form when all that fields that you use are native on Symfony from a time ago? But not matter, what you're looking for is how to customize Form render and if so take a look to this [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) hope it helps

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I chose to use these MoneyType class from TBBC instead of native text + choice classes because TBBC MoneyType enables the form widget to be automatically filled with currencies I have previously declared in the config file (I have just 3 or 4 I want to use), seemed to be the most "standard" way to have them integrated in the form instead of re-declaring them. I will have another look at symfony documentation and try to customize the MoneyType in the twig file, but I am still not sure where to start from ;-)

Comment: Take a look to *What are Form Themes?* it will help you to understand how form are themed and therefore make your own changes, is easy if you get stuck let me know and I will try to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replying to myself...
As correctly indicated in the bundle documentation I had to configure my config.yml to declare the new type to twig:

```
# config.yml
twig:
    form:
        resources:
            - 'TbbcMoneyBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
```

The form elements are rendered much better and should be easily customizable.

Answer (score 0):

Theme a widget or form in Symfony is well documented [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) and IMO you should go through [*Inside the same Template as the Form*](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-1-inside-the-same-template-as-the-form). You could extends from `form_div_layout.html.twig` and then on your custom template overrides how `money_widget` is render by changing the following block:

```
{%- block money_widget -%}
    {{ money_pattern|replace({ '{{ widget }}': block('form_widget_simple') })|raw }}
{%- endblock money_widget -%}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @ReynierPM. Actually I just found what i was doing wrong with the bundle, I had missed the configuration of twig form dedicated to the bundle in my config.yml, now the fields are displayed much better and I think I will be able to customize them much more easily than I thought! I will read the template customization though since it should be quite useful in the near future. Thanks again.

Comment: Good to heard I could help, please if my answer contribute feel free to accept it ;) good luck